# Twitter Bootstrap - Color Picker

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to integrate a [color picker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/) in my site. However, I integrated:

```
<link href="css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!--Color Picker -->
<script src="js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
 <script>
$(function(){
window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
$('#cp1').colorpicker({
format: 'hex'
});
$('#cp2').colorpicker();
$('#cp3').colorpicker();
var bodyStyle = $('body')[0].style;
$('#cp4').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
bodyStyle.backgroundColor = ev.color.toHex();
});
});
</script>
```

and the colorpicker component:

```
 <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Pick the color of your product</label>
      <div class="controls">
   <div id="cp3" class="input-append color" data-color-format="rgb" data-color="rgb(255, 146, 180)">
      <input class="span2" type="text" readonly="" value="">
      <span class="add-on">
      <i style="background-color: rgb(255, 146, 180)"></i>
      </span>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, when I call my site the color picker looks like that:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reset the image paths of `alpha.png`, `hue.png` and `saturation.png` in `colorpicker.css` to the folder where you have stored them.

```
.colorpicker-hue { background-image: url(your/path/hue.png) };
```

Answer (score 4):

I did need of using a color picker for Twitter Bootstrap and i found [jQuery MiniColors: A tiny color picker built on jQuery](https://github.com/claviska/jquery-minicolors). It was good but i wanted to keep my web as light as possible, so i realized that HTML5 give us the `type="color"` possibility, so you can use in your *bootstrap based page* something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Color de letra</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7 input-group color-picker">
            <input id="textColor" type="color" value="" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It will work this way:

[image]